# How to detect multiple WebSocket connections from the same computer?

Tags: javascript, websocket

I have a Node.js WebSocket server and I want to prevent clients from being able to open 50 tabs which will create 50 connections. My current idea is to check the IP addresses like this:

```
ws._socket.remoteAddress
```

and then just check that against my current connections IPs and if that IP already exists then reject the connection request. My understanding is that there will be a problem with this approach because if 2 computers are on the same Wifi and therefore have the same public IP, the second computer will be blocked. This isn't what I want. I want 1 connection per computer, therefore IP might not be the solution. Is this a valid problem or would my solution actually work? What is the best way to uniquely identify a client's computer to prevent more than 1 connection on that device?

Comment: You can use cookies

Comment: I should have specified this, I specifically can't use cookies for privacy reasons. Is there not a standard way of doing this via the library and what I already have access to on connection?

Comment: HTTP is a stateless protocol.  Other than cookies (and some ambiguous headers like `User-Agent`), there is fundamentally no difference between requests from different computers behind the same IP.

Comment: What you're asking for has the same privacy implications as cookies (identifying a computer).

Comment: Okay, so what you're saying is that there is no way to prevent fake user spamming from the same device without cookies or a token? Currently, I have users that are authenticated and they send JWT over. I'm looking to open up connections to users before they sign up now so they won't be authed, but don't want to have a spam problem. Appreciate the fast responses.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you control the clients connecting, I would look at a shared web worker that is used by all tabs in that browser. This would essentially give you 1 connection for n tabs. Each browser would be a new connection though so maybe 3-4 connections at most?

Here is a link. Check out the example as it spells it out pretty succinctly: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker

Comment: This is exactly the kind of solution I'm looking for, however, it looks like this isn't supported in Safari, Edge, or IE. That's too large of the market missing for this to be considered a viable solution for me. Do you have any other ideas to prevent spam like this?